# Change raven menu's power strip options under Budgie

Tags: desktop-environments, customization, budgie

I'd like to customize budgie a bit further than what's made available in it's "Budgie Desktop Settings"

For the "Raven" tab we can enable the "Power Strip" but the name is quite false advertizing because out of the three buttons it adds, none are "power"-related, rather they are "session"-related :

- Settings (this one strikes me as even less on topic but I guess it's inspired by vanilla ubuntu)
- Lock
- and Logout

I'd like to at the very least have "power". but ideally I'd like to have more options such as restart, why not the same functionality as ubuntu-vanilla where, upon holding alt "power" is replaced with "sleep".

so ideally :

- Settings
- Lock
- Hibernate
- and Shutdown

So basically are there customizable files that aren't replaced by an update that I could modify to attain this affect, or some plugin that I could install?